# Opening MIDI in DAW

Tags: midi

I sometimes get MIDI files from sites like www.midiworld.com
Sometimes the MIDI file has all instruments on a single track.
How can I separate such files into separate tracks?

(Am using Ableton btw)

Thanks

Comment: Unless there is one instrument per note in the MIDI file (like a MIDI file for drums for example) it probably won't be possible. Most modern DAWs have a function for splitting MIDI files by note. In Logic Pro this is termed 'Demix by Note Pitch', maybe there's something similar in Ableton?

Answer (score 1):

MIDI just carries event information like notation, pitch, velocity etc. So you're incorrect in claiming that a midi file would have different instruments on a single midi region. If the creator of those midi regions intended for different midi notes to be used for different instruments then it's careless for them to include them as one single midi file and this is beyond any help we can offer as I assume each instrument has separate notations.  Otherwise you're using your own artistic discretion to separate a single midi region, so it's for you to decide how you want it split.

However, once you know exactly what needs splitting, 
1. Copy that item (ctrl-drag) to all 5 tracks.

2. Open them one at a time in MIDI editor. (Double click the item).
3. Zoom horizontally so far that you can see the whole length of the item.
4. Lasso (Right drag) the notes you don´t want on that track and delete.

Pros: You have just those notes you want on the tracks!
Cons: This is manual labor!

Comment: I know what you mean about manual processing, however, it becomes difficult when different instruments share the same octave space. Check out this midi file for an example http://www.midiworld.com/download/427 i really don't know whether I'm doing something wrong or if these midi sites are distributing useless information. I imagine the former

Comment: Works fine on GarageBand; so must be an Abelton configuration issue of some sort. I'd recommend posting on an abelton user forum: http://tinypic.com/r/2urnsyq/9